# In Javamail for EWS store, FlagTerm to check for unread mails in outlook mailbox is not giving correct results

Tags: jakarta-mail, exchangewebservices

I am trying to connect to my outlook mailbox using Javamail for EWS and fetch the details of unread emails from my outlook mailbox. It is connecting to the mailbox and giving total mails count correctly. I have used flagterm to check for unseen emails and did folder search with this flag. But the count of my unseen messages is always returned 0 despite of unseen mails existing in mailbox. Please find my code snippet below:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("org.sourceforge.net.javamail4ews.util.Util.EnableServiceTrace", "true");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
    session.setDebug(true);

    Store store = session.getStore("ewsstore");

    store.connect(
                    "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx",
                    "xyz@hotmail.com",
                    "Password");

    Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
    FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, false); //When flag set true,its giving total count
    Message[] messagesunread = folder.search(unseenFlagTerm);

    System.out.println(messagesunread.length);
```